# I don't know what this is?

Tags: species-identification

I went into my shed today and found this bloody spot with something I'm not sure what it was. Have any idea??? [image]

Answer (score 1):

These are the intestines (greenish bits), kidneys (pale bean shapes) and probably liver (dark red) of an animal that has been eaten by a predator.

Exactly which animal they come from is almost impossible to determine without more of a sense of scale, however, from the size of fly in the front, I would guess probably mouse to small rat sized.

Which predator left these is also hard to say, though domestic cats often leave the innards.

Comment: Thank you! We do have feral cats around and thought that might be what it was. Well it was one of a few guesses lol

Comment: @MelissaE Yeah, cats are everywhere. Even your most domesticated if cats is capable if doing this, and almost certainly does if they are have free access to the outside at night. If you think this is the right answer, please mark as accepted by clicking the green tick mark.